# click row to fill textboxes in php - array vs ajax

Tags: php

I have a table coded in php which pulls in data from mysql database and displays it in a html table . Now when i click on a row I need certain textboxes to be filled.

What is the best approach for this: is it using an array or ajax,html and php,

```
<?php
$default = "<img src='http://localhost/on.png' width='24' height='24'/>";
 $default1 = "<img src='http://localhost/of.png' width='24' height='24'/>";
 $con = mysql_connect("*****","******","******");
if (!$con){
 die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
 mysql_select_db ("*****",$con);
$sql= "select act.*
 from audit_activity as act
  inner join (
      select user_id, max(timestamp) as max_ts
      from activity
      group by user_id) as a on act.user_id=a.user_id and act.timestamp=a.max_ts";
 $mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);

 echo "<table id='tfhover',table border=0>
<tr>
 <th>Users</th>
 <th>Status<th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['user_id'] . "</td>";
if (strtolower(trim($record['activity']))!=strtolower('LOGIN')){ 
echo "<td>" . $default1  . "</td>";
}else{

 echo "<td>" . $default  . "</td>";
}



echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
;


mysql_close($con);

?>


<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
var tbRow=[];
for (var i=1;i<tfrow;i++) {
    tbRow[i]=document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
    tbRow[i].onmouseover = function(){
      this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    };
    tbRow[i].onmouseout = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = '#d4e3e5';
    };
}
 };
  </script>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>


  Total exams taken  : <br>
<input type="text" name="fname"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please give brief description of your requirement, also add code and write what you have tried?

Comment: you have to use ajax+html+php

Comment: You have to use Javascript only. Please post HTML table here

Comment: there you are i have updated my code

Comment: We still need more information to be helpful. You need to fill _which_ textboxes with _what_ information? Data from the table, from another source, dynamic/static information... If it's data from your table or otherwise information already on the page, then jQuery is your man, otherwise, you're gonna need some ajax to fill in other dynamic data.